# PyCharm with pytest run configuration fail importerror PyQt5 with pipenv

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5, pycharm

I have difficulties setting up PyCharm to run my tests correctly while using a pipenv interpreter

if i run my tests through a terminal with

```
pipenv run pytest
```

it works perfectly because it loads the `.env` file correctly
however i can't make it work with the integrated pytest run configuration.
I even tried with the EnvFile PyCharm plugin but i can't make it work.

i get this error:

```py
C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path D:/plugins/path_finding/tests
Testing started at 11:03 ...
Launching pytest with arguments D:/plugins/path_finding/tests in D:\plugins\path_finding\tests

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-4.4.0, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: D:\plugins\path_finding\tests
plugins: cov-2.7.1
collecting ... 
test_graphs.py:None (test_graphs.py)
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\plugins\path_finding\tests\test_graphs.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:511: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:704: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:299: in load_module
    six.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
test_graphs.py:13: in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\__init__.py:74: in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py:24: in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
E   ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________________ ERROR collecting test_graphs.py _______________________
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\plugins\path_finding\tests\test_graphs.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:511: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:704: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
C:\Users\lcottereau\.virtualenvs\path_finding-4c165HCr\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:299: in load_module
    six.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
test_graphs.py:13: in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\__init__.py:74: in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py:24: in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
E   ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.28 seconds ===========================

Process finished with exit code 2
```

contents of .env file (might have some unnecessary variables set but I put everything i could think of inside):

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

QGIS_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16
PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\bin;${WINDIR}\system32;${WINDIR};${WINDIR}\system32\WBem
PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qt5\bin;${PATH}

GDAL_DATA=${QGIS_ROOT}\share\gdal
PROJ_LIB=${QGIS_ROOT}\share\proj

QT_PLUGIN_PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\plugins
O4W_QT_PREFIX=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5
O4W_QT_BINARIES=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\bin
O4W_QT_PLUGINS=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\plugins
O4W_QT_LIBRARIES=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\lib
O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\translations
O4W_QT_HEADERS=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\include
O4W_QT_DOC=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Qt5\doc


GDAL_DATA=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\gdal2\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\gdal2\bin\gdalplugins
PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\gdal2\bin;${PATH}
PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;${PATH}

QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qgis-ltr
GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
VSI_CACHE=TRUE
VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qt5\plugins
PYTHONPATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qgis-ltr\python;${PYTHONPATH}
PYTHONPATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Python37\Lib;${PYTHONPATH}
PYTHONPATH=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\qgis-ltr\Lib\site-packages;${PYTHONPATH}
PYTHONHOME=${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Python37
PATH=${PATH};${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Python37;${QGIS_ROOT}\apps\Python37\Scripts
```

Comment: Not quite sure, what's wrong, because I use bat files to start python related programs. If a DLL error accures it could be in my opinion a missing directory in the path variable, or a wrong order of pathes. It could also be a version conflict, if python references to a newer dll version than installed, but I think that's the case here.

Comment: A missing path is what I assume whoever It works with pipenv in a terminal loading these paths but I haven't been able to replicate that environment path loading through the integrated pycharm pytest runner

Comment: BTW I also use a bat file to start my pycharm but that doesn't help in my case